# Can't write to SD Card with permissions

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

I've been struggling to write on the sd card for quite some time and I've finally come to realize that there's a new kind of "permissions" for this job exclusively.
First of all, this is the code which I use, hoping to get the permission and not need it later:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
startActivityForResult(intent, RCODE);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RCODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Uri treeUri = data.getData();
        DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);
        grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), treeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        App.editor.putBoolean("writable",true).apply();App.editor.commit();
    }
}
```

and here's the code I use to delete the files:

```
public static boolean deleteFile(Context context, File f){
    if (isOnInternal(f)){
        return f.delete();
    }else{
        String path = "/document/";
        String tp = f.getAbsolutePath().replace(getsdpath(),"").substring(1);
        path += getsdpath().replace("/storage/","")+":"+tp;
        Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
                .scheme("content")
                .authority("com.android.externalstorage.documents")
                .path(path)
                .build();
        Log.e("path1",uri.getPath());
        return DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context,uri).delete();
    }
}
```

Here's the LogCat message when I want to delete a file:

```
W/Documents: Failed to delete document
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/1CE2-0E0E%3Aimg.jpg from pid=3000, uid=10060 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:646)
    at android.content.ContentProviderClient.call(ContentProviderClient.java:437)
    at android.provider.DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(DocumentsContract.java:1015)
    at android.provider.DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(DocumentsContract.java:999)
    at android.support.v4.provider.SingleDocumentFile.delete(SingleDocumentFile.java:98)
    at ir.coders.nahan.Utils.FileUtils.deleteFile(FileUtils.java:41)
    at ir.coders.nahan.App.deleteFile(App.java:314)
    at ir.coders.nahan.Activities.HidePics.lambda$onActivityResult$7(HidePics.java:230)
    at ir.coders.nahan.Activities.-$$Lambda$HidePics$Vwwkfk8tS-KV0NE8pJgYHtkKXnI.run(lambda)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here are both paths taken by the below method:

```
uri.getPath();
the tree which I grant the permission from: /tree/1CE2-0E0E:
the file : /document/1CE2-0E0E:img.jpg
```

The code I use to delete the file is an attempt to duplicate the original URI made by android itslef when user chooses the file but it doesn't seem to work as planned.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you print both the paths, the one you request from `grantUriPermission()` and the one you try to write to?

Comment: Isn't `grantUriPermission` supposed to be called by the file/document provider you queried for document uri? I think that was the entire point of obfuscating direct file uris so they will only be accessible as read-only.

Comment: @shkschneider edited!

Comment: @Pawel what do you suggest I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the tree which I grant the permission from: /tree/1CE2-0E0E:
>
> the file : /document/1CE2-0E0E:img.jpg

The URI's roots are not the same. Inspect those two URIs as their do not look alike. I suspect that's the issue.

Somehow you should re-use the URI you sent `grantUriPermission()`

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Add `MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` to your permissions either in manifest or through code. 
Your other permissions don't seem to cover this specific permission.

Comment: MANAGE_DOCUMENTS is only supposed to be granted by System apps through the manifest.

Comment: I guess i'm going to have to fix some bad code smell.